# Splitting Name into last name, first name, middle initial

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a user input from a textbox that contains a user's name

input can look like this:

```
var input = "Doe, John M";
```

However, input can be a whole lot more complex.
like:

```
var input = "Doe Sr, John M"
```

or `"Doe, John M"`

or `"Doe, John, M"`

or even `"Doe Sr, John,M"`

What I'd like to do is separate the last name (with the sr or jr) the first name, and then the middle initial.

So, these strings become :

`var input = "Doe#John#M"` or `"Doe Sr#John#M"` or `"Doe#John#M"`

I've tried this regular expression,

`input = input.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, '#');`
but this doesn't take into account the last middle initial.

Comment: Forget it. Have a field for first, middle if any and last

Comment: What he said ^^^^^^^^^^^ !

Comment: You should control how users input their info, not the other way around :). Just give them the input options the way you want it. They'll just have to abide. And they will ;)

Comment: Please consider the case of having more than one middle initial too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to match your requirements

```
input = input.replace(/\s*,\s*|\s+(?=\S+$)/g, '#');
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this can probably be done via RegEx but splitting the string into arrays is often faster and a little less complex (IMO). Try this function:

```
var parseName = function(s) {
  var last = s.split(',')[0];
  var first = s.split(',')[1].split(' ')[1];
  var mi = s[s.length-1];

  return {
    first: first,
    mi: mi,
    last: last
  };    
};
```

You call it just passing in the name e.g. `parseName('Doe, John M')` and it returns an object with `first`, `mi`, `last`. I created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofusik/1/) you can try that tests the formats of names you show in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout `humanparser` on npm.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/humanparser

Parse a human name string into salutation, first name, middle name, last name, suffix.

Install

```
npm install humanparser
```

Usage

```
var human = require('humanparser');

var fullName = 'Mr. William R. Jenkins, III'
    , attrs = human.parseName(fullName);

console.log(attrs);

//produces the following output

{ saluation: 'Mr.',
  firstName: 'William',
  suffix: 'III',
  lastName: 'Jenkins',
  middleName: 'R.',
  fullName: 'Mr. William R. Jenkins, III' }
```